# Android Bitmap image return null after decode from content Uri image

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

I'm working on loading all images from SDcard and display in GridView. I was using AsyncTask to load Image Content Uri from background thread and decode via BitmapFactory.Options. But, the problem was the decoded bitmap image return **NULL**. Can anyone kindly let me know the error or help to solve? Thanks!

In onCreate() method

```
 LoadImageTask task = new LoadImageTask();
    task.execute();
```

AsyncTask to load Image Content Uri using cursor

```
public class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog showDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog = new ProgressDialog(GalleryActivity.this);
        showDialog.setMessage("Loading images...");
        showDialog.setCancelable(false);
        showDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        showDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            String[] list = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, list,
                    null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

            for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageID + "");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
             Log.e(TAG,e + "");
            }
            return null;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        showDialog.dismiss();
        adapter = new ImageAdapter(GalleryActivity.this, cursor);
        mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
Cursor c;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    mContext = context;
    c = cursor;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return c.getCount();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public  View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.grid_item,parent,false);;
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    Bitmap bm = GalleryActivity.decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(GalleryActivity.uri + "", 200, 200);
    Log.i(GalleryActivity.TAG, bm + "");  // after log return null
    holder.gridImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

    return convertView;
}}
```

Bitmap Decoding

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    Bitmap bm;
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    return bm;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
{
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 2;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Logcat

```
04-13 19:29:47.868 3973-3973/com.yang.wallpaperchanger I/GalleryActivity: null
```

I had done research at stackoverflow and other website but still unable to get solution. Appreciated your help !

Comment: Why are you not using volley or picasso library which are more efficient and out of memory  issue handling properly and caching logic too.

Comment: Why are you trying to log Bitmap? `Log.i(GalleryActivity.TAG, bm + "");`. Try this: `Log.i(GalleryActivity.TAG, (bm!=null?"YEAH":"NULL"));`

Comment: by logging the bitmap, I guess he wants to see if it´s null...

Comment: have you ever checked if the path is correct?

Comment: `the problem was the decoded bitmap image return NULL` ???? Do you mean that `BitmapFactory.decodeFile() returns null` ?

Comment: `return inSampleSize;`. Please tell the returned value(s).

Comment: have you added the permission to read external storage?

Comment: You are loading and decoding images on the main application thread. **DO NOT DO THIS**. Please use [an image loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), to handle your image loading.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs the path is retrieved from 
Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageID + "");
and by logging it, it shown the correct image path. Just getting null after decode into bitmap. I had added the permission too.

Comment: @greenapps ya..BitmapFactory.decodeFile() return null . Value of inSampleSize return 2.

Comment: Is the insample size value correct? Why dont you comment on it? Shouldnt it be higher? Calculate yourself. The value is to low. Thats why decodeFile returns null. Your jpg file is too big to expand to a bitmap for lack of memory.

Comment: @CommonsWare  I'm changing to use picasso library to load images from sdcard. It successfully loaded. However, the loaded images keep reloading when I scrolling in Gridview. How can I fix this? thanks